# new community - How to build the audience little by little

Tags: social-network

If you have created a new social network about a niche, targeting a small group of people if compared to giants like twitter or facebook, what is your idea to start building an audience little by little ?

I started to use twitter but I do not think it is very effective as a method of public relationship.

I sent some e-mails to some blog related about the subject of the social network but I did not get too much (Just an e-mail to two persone per day, no spam or any aggressive behaviour).

I have to say, I have a finished the ideas. Relying just on SEO and a good position on the search engines, I am afraid it is not very smart.

Any good angel capable to give an idea ?

Comment: There are many questions already about [community growth](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+grow)